# How to get the data in xml file by using xsd file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am doing TDD unit testing, I get my test case fail due to the error as below:

> Data Table 'http://tempuri.org/ProjectManagerDS.xsd:MetricModelInput does not match to any Data Table in source'

I realize that my data in **ResourceModelinfo.xml** really does not match to the Data Table in **ProjectManagerDS.xsd**.

How do I get the data according to **ProjectManagerDS.xsd**?

Code:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CreateNewRowTest1()
    {
        ProjectManagerBL target = new ProjectManagerBL();
        target.ProjectManagerDS = new ProjectManagerDS();

        //Start Added by XMei on 4/29/15
        //DataSet objDS = new DataSet();
        //DataTable dt;

        //dt = objDS.Tables.Add("MarketCodeNames");
        //dt.Columns.Add("Selected", Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
        //dt.Columns.Add("MarketCodeNameValue", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        //dt.Rows.Add("True", "HVM-MOR");
        //dt.Rows.Add("False", "HVM-POR");
        //End Added by XMei on 4/29/15

        target.ProjectManagerDS.MetricModelInput.ReadXml(@"..\\..\\..\\TestBusinessLogic\\ResourceModelinfo.xml");

        ProjectManagerDS.MetricModelInputRow MMIrow = target.ProjectManagerDS.MetricModelInput[0];

        DataRow Actual = target.CreateNewRow(MMIrow, "To-BE");

        Assert.IsNotNull(Actual);

    }
```

ProjectManagerDS.cs

```
    namespace XXX.ATMSS.MetricSystem.DataObject {


    partial class ProjectManagerDS
    {
        partial class MetricModelsDataTable
        {
        }

        partial class MetricModelInputDataTable
        {
        }

        partial class MfgStageDataTable
        {
        }

        partial class ResourcesDataTable
        {
        }

        partial class UserListDataTable
        {
        }
    }
}
```

For ProjectManagerDS.xsd, there is a table in relationship form, I could not upload a picture here because my reputation is not yet reach 10.

Comment: Some code, perhaps?  A complete sample that would allow others to reproduce the issue would be nice.  It's not clear what 'Data Table' has to do with anything or what you're doing to get this error.

Comment: I have edited as above.

Comment: I do refer to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/400016/Generate-Sample-XML-from-XSD, but there is no XML Schema Explorer under my View tab